# Why does type casting not work the same in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, casting, firebase

```
firebase!.observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { [weak self] (snapshot) in    
    if let stuff: AnyObject = snapshot.value {
            let from_user_id = stuff["from_user_id"] as? Int //warning
            let value = stuff["value"] as? Int  //warning

        }
}
```

I'm getting the warning:

`Cast from 'MDLMaterialProperty?!' to unrelated type 'Int' always fails`

observeEventType is declared as:

```
func observeEventType(eventType: FEventType, withBlock block: ((FDataSnapshot!) -> Void)!) -> UInt
Description 
observeEventType:withBlock: is used to listen for data changes at a particular location. This is the primary way to read data from Firebase. Your block will be triggered for the initial data and again whenever the data changes.
Use removeObserverWithHandle: to stop receiving updates.
Parameters  
eventType   
The type of event to listen for.
block   
The block that should be called with initial data and updates. It is passed the data as an FDataSnapshot.
Returns 
A handle used to unregister this block later using removeObserverWithHandle:
Declared In Firebase.h
```

snapshot.value is defined as:

```
var value: AnyObject! { get }
Description 
Returns the contents of this data snapshot as native types.
Data types returned: * NSDictionary * NSArray * NSNumber (also includes booleans) * NSString
Returns 
The data as a native object.
Declared In FDataSnapshot.h
```

Comment: Why you don't use the real type of 'stuff' instead of using AnyObject? As I red the code, you should know what type is 'stuff' when doing 'if let stuff: put_here_the_specific_type' .

Comment: @CiprianC snapshot.value is declared as ```var value: AnyObject! { get }```

Comment: @TIMEX You should show your definition for `MDLMaterialProperty`. Without knowing the types in there we can only guess at what's happening.

Comment: Could you put the definition of the function `observeEventType`?

Comment: @DanielZhang I'm using the Firebase module from cocoapods. I have no idea what MDLMaterialProperty is, but this is from a basic Firebase example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't subscript AnyObject. Have to cast it to a dictionary.
You'll also want to be sure those values are Ints.

```
  firebase!.observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { [weak self] (snapshot) in    
            if let stuff = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    let from_user_id = stuff["from_user_id"] as? Int
                    let value = stuff["value"] as? Int
                }
        }
```

Comment: I get this: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(MDLMaterialProperty?!)'. I also want the two variables to be optionals.

Comment: Alright, AnyObject can't be cast to Int, because Int, isn't an object.

Comment: ```Cast from 'MDLMaterialProperty?!' to unrelated type 'NSNumber' always fails```

Comment: ```Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject!' to specified type '[String : AnyObject]?'```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
firebase!.observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { [weak self] (snapshot) in
    if let stuff = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
        if let from_user_id = stuff["from_user_id"] as? Int {
            // Do something with from_user_id.
        }
        if let value = stuff["value"] as? Int {
            // Do something with value.
        }
    }
}
```

Using optional binding will be the safest way to handle potentially nil values along with potentially incompatible types when casting from AnyObject in Swift 2.

Comment: ```Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject!' to specified type 'NSDictionary?'```

Comment: @TIMEX I've updated it to use an optional cast. Let me know if that works.